# How to set frame options inside a beamertemplate?

Tags: beamer, templates, themes

Is there a command like `\thispagestyle` in order to set in a beamer template the `plain` option (for example).

I need this in order to design a section page template were I would like to remove sidebar head/footline. Thus I would like to be able to say in the beamertemplate : `this frame is plain`.

Actually this is done for the `title page` but looking at the default theme I do not find how.

Comment: Is the `plain` option passed to a given frame sufficient?

Comment: Yes I can do `\frame[plain]{\sectionpage}`. But, as the plain option has to be set to all `\sectionpage` it would be better to set the plain option into the beamertemplate.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323638/36296 you could automatcally remove the footline and headline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 

\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@sectionpage{%
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}%
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}%
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
\addtobeamertemplate{section page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@sectionpage}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
    test 
\end{frame}

\section{bla}
\begin{frame}
    \sectionpage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} 
    test1 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]